# Where can I find Chromium binary tarballs?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, tar, binary

Firefox's website provides binary tarballs that I can easily extract and run, is there anything similar available for either Chrome or Chromium?

If not, how can I compile so I can run it the same way as the extracted files of binary tarball?

Answer (score 9):

All the Chromium builds for different systems are stored [**here**](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) as **zip** archives.

Binaries for Linux: [**32 bit**](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Linux/) | [**64 bit**](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Linux_x64/)
<sup>(It takes a while to load the list)</sup>

The latest 64-bit version is located here:

```
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_x64/LATEST/chrome-linux.zip
```

Where **`LATEST`** is contents of the file located here:

```
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_x64/LAST_CHANGE
```

<sup>If you need the 32-bit version, remove `_x64` from those links</sup>

This allows us to make a script to automatically download the latest build:

```
#!/bin/bash
CHROMIUM_ROOT="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_x64"
CHROMIUM_LATEST=`wget -q -O - "$CHROMIUM_ROOT/LAST_CHANGE"`
wget $CHROMIUM_ROOT/$CHROMIUM_LATEST/chrome-linux.zip
```

Comment: How regularly do you suggest I check for and download the latest build?

Comment: @Oxwivi: Maybe once a week? By the way, those builds aren't guaranteed to even work. I think you should just add [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/dev) and you will get quite fresh and quite stable builds of Chromium which will be updated together with your regular updates.

Comment: I don't want installation packages like Deb.

Comment: @Oxwivi: it's not `deb` – _

Comment: My bad for not checking it out. Well, I tried your script, doesn't work with either `_x64` or otherwise.

Comment: Note, the folders now may have changed, so see https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium -> https://download-chromium.appspot.com/ -> https://github.com/scheib/chromium-latest-linux -> https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2FLAST_CHANGE?alt=media

Answer (score 1):

In short there are no official tarballs of Chrome but if you don't mind breaking your profile you can try the [continuous build tarballs mentioned in this Chromium-discuss group](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-discuss/msg/777f0f54f4452b4d?utoken=DJWVJTAAAADEegZ-hvtfsD25KJ60Nkijbso0IWocoK8uI0Nw8UahtwyWP2Ehnzsu4tkg1CckgBU) (and definitely avoid the nightly builds).

If you are on Ubuntu you are far better off using prepackaged version of Chrome. [Google provide Chrome repositories for the major Linux distributions](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel). If you're desperate, you could always download the deb/rpm and extract the contents and get the whole caboodle going with the wrapper script from a continuous build...

Comment: The prepackaged version of Chromium (in the offical repositories) is like 3 versions stale. If you're going to suggest using prebuilt binaries, you *need* to mention [this guy](https://launchpad.net/~a-v-shkop). Google does offer an official repository for their Chrome browser, but the asker specifically mentioned Chromium (probably because he doesn't want Google breathing down his neck ;)